# <f:convertDateTime> is not displaying the right system date and time

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 2.0. In bean I am setting `Date` using `java.util.Date` and if I am printing that date with normally `<h:outputText value="#{payment.statusChangeDate}">` then I am getting system date and time. But when I am using

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm" />
```

Then it is giving a different time with date. But I need to display current system date and time.

I have also tried

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

To get the default system time zone but still I am getting wrong time.

Comment: What *exactly* does it display without and with the converter? Please update your question to include that detail.

Comment: Without <f:convertDateTime> tag it is displaying the System current date and time but once i am trying to use this tag...it is showing date as same but wrong time.Is this issue is related to time-zone setting or any thing else ?? Please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" timeZone="GB"/>
```

Comment: there is no need to place the original question in your answer, just provide an answer.